# When fetching data from multiple tables it is not showing any error however i am not able to retrieve the data

Tags: java, sql, database

```
String get_date = txt_check_in_date.getText().trim();
        String get_customer_no = txt_customer_no.getText().trim();
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        try{
            String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel";
            String userid ="root";
            String password ="tushar11";
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid,password);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select occupantdetails.customer_name, hoteldetails.service_detail, hoteldetails.room_no from occupantdetails JOIN hoteldetails ON occupantdetails.customer_no=hoteldetails.customer_no where occupantdetails.customer_no=? AND occupantdetails.check_in_date=? " );
            pstmt.setString(1, get_date);
            pstmt.setString(2, get_customer_no);



            rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(rst.next()){
                txt_customer_name.setText(rst.getString("customer_name"));
                txt_room_no.setText(rst.getString("service_detail"));
                txt_cab_no.setText(rst.getString("room_no"));
            }
```

when i run the file and fill in the parameters it is not showing any error and the execution stops. And no result is displayed.

Comment: What happens when you try this query without using java?

Comment: Little bit off topic - naming convention for variables it so have camelCasedNames like `txtCustomerName`

Comment: What is the format of get_date? Does it matches the date format of occupantdetails.check_in_date? If it does not match use date format function to match

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks i am new to java and learning. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to java, so not sure about this..
Order of parameter is different, In query order number appears first and then order date and it is reverse while adding parameters..
Does that matter?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really worked. Did a silly mistake.